# How do I set the background color in VBA so I can detect it in a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to set duplicate values to red in column B. I cannot remember where this came from. I added the counter and msgbox to see that something was happening. Duplicate values in column B are highlighted as red.

```
Sub formatduplicates2()
Dim rg As Range
Dim cf As FormatCondition
Dim datax As Range
Dim xcolor As Long
Dim colorcount
Dim count

colorcount = 1
Set rg = Range("B17", Range("B17").End(xlDown))
Set cf = rg.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF(B$17:B17,B17)>1")
cf.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
For Each datax In rg
    count = count + 1
    If count = 10000 Then
        MsgBox count
    End If
Next datax

End Sub
```

I am using the following function to count all the red cells. This is from Ozgrid. It works if I manually change a cell's background color.

The cells that are changed using the code above are not seen by the function. When I manually check the background color of the cells in column B (the ones that are obviously red) Excel tells me the RGB settings are 0,0,0 (no fill).  No amount of recalculating or saving and reopening the file changes anything. The cells look red, but the data associated with it is "no fill".

My goal is to count the cells of a given background.

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional StrCond As String) As Long

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult As Long

    lCol = rColor.Interior.Color

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
            If StrCond <> "" Then
                If rCell.Value = StrCond Then
                    vResult = vResult + 1
                End If
            Else
                vResult = vResult + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

Comment: That won't detect CF formatting. Use the CF condition or there is a VBA alternative - from memory it's something like displayformat.

Comment: You have to work with a `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` if you are dealing with conditional formatting.

Comment: I am not sure where I would insert the code you mention

Comment: Are you using `ColorFunction` on your worksheet, or calling it using VBA?

Comment: @Drummo2a change  `lCol = rColor.Interior.Color` to `lCol = rColor.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` and `rCell.Interior.Color = lCol` to `rCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = lCol`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding cells with certain interior color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336135/finding-cells-with-certain-interior-color)

Comment: Now I get a #Value! error even on the manually colored cells

Comment: In regard to BigBen - I am not using ColorFunction, and would not know how to use it.

Comment: Your function is named `ColorFunction` - a little confused by your last comment. It sounds like you are using this as a UDF (i.e. you are entering `=ColorFunction(...` on your worksheet. If you want to use this as a UDF, the current approach won't work and you'll get the #Value! error. There is an alternate VBA approach, but the simplest is probably just an Excel formula to count duplicates. Also, please use the "@" - i.e @BigBen to notify someone in a comment.

Comment: Oops, I see what you are saying, I am using ColorFunction as a formula in the worksheet

Comment: My file is very big, counting duplicates was going down a path that led to Excel not responding or it took an hour to check things.  The path I am on now seems to be faster.  Still not sure why the changes from @dwirony changed the formula from working to error

Comment: To me , the issue seems to be where does Excel hide the color format and how can I extract it.  It seems that the conditional formatting hides things from both VB and within the spreadsheet itself, yet the cell is red!

Comment: The conditional formatting is the cell's `DisplayFormat`, as was called out earlier. If you want a UDF, it will have to evaluate the formula you've used for your conditional formatting - the original `=COUNTIF(B$17:B17,B17)>1` to see if it is true for **every cell in your range**. So you'll still end up doing a lot of calculations - which is why I proposed counting duplicates. What were you using to do that originally?

Comment: This page has a good explanation of the troubles of conditional formatting, along with code to count conditionallly formatted cells. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm From a brief read through/test, if you still want to go the UDF way you'll need to modify/simplify it.

Comment: There is a sample UDF [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/How-to-count-and-sum-quot-Condtional-formatting-quot-cells-by/td-p/116110) that shows to count cells by conditional formatting color.

Comment: @BigBen *You have to work with a `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`*. Won't work in Excel <=2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are coloring cells with conditional formatting **using a formula to determine which cells to format**, this UDF will count the number of cells with that color (adapted from [Microsoft Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/sum-by-color-when-colors-are-set-by-conditional-formatting/m-p/36495#M15)).

You can normally determine the color applied by conditional formatting by using a range's `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`, as opposed to its `Interior.Color`. If you modified your `ColorFunction` to look at `rCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` and used that Function within a `Sub`, i.e. something like this, it would work fine.

```
Sub Test
    Range("A2").Value = ColorFunction(Range("A1"), Range("B17:B20"))
End Sub
```

However `ColorFunction` **will not work** as a UDF - your `#Value!` error as mentioned in the comments. I'm not completely sure on the reason why, but apparently using `Range.DisplayFormat` will not work with a UDF. So to have a UDF, you need to loop through each range and evaluate the formula associated with the conditional format.

Two slight wrinkles in that approach:

1. You need to determine which  `FormatCondition` of the `Range` you want to consider, if there are multiple.
2. The formula associated with the "right" `FormatCondition` - in your original case `=COUNTIF(B$17:B17,B17)>1` - will not automatically update relative references, if it has any. You'll need to use `Application.ConvertFormula`, converting from *A1* to *R1C1* (and back to *A1*) reference style, while using the *RelativeTo* argument to update the relative references.

---

```
Function CountConditionColorCells(CellsRange As Range, ColorRng As Range) As Long
    Dim RightCF As Boolean
    Dim CFformula As String
    Dim CFCELL As Range
    Dim CFcounter, CFtrueCounter As Long, CFCellCounter As Long

    ' Determines which conditional format to consider, if multiple
    For CFcounter = 1 To CellsRange.FormatConditions.Count
        If CellsRange.FormatConditions(CFcounter).Interior.ColorIndex = ColorRng.Interior.ColorIndex Then
            RightCF = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next CFcounter

    If RightCF Then
        For Each CFCELL In CellsRange
            CFformula = CFCELL.FormatConditions(CFcounter).Formula1
            CFformula = Application.ConvertFormula(CFformula, xlA1, xlR1C1)
            CFformula = Application.ConvertFormula(CFformula, xlR1C1, xlA1, , _
                ActiveCell.Resize(CellsRange.Rows.Count, CellsRange.Columns.Count).Cells(CFCellCounter + 1))

            If Evaluate(CFformula) Then CFtrueCounter = CFtrueCounter + 1

            CFCellCounter = CFCellCounter + 1
        Next CFCELL
    Else
        Exit Function ' Returns 0
    End If

    CountConditionColorCells = CFtrueCounter
End Function
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Seems to work, but I need a better way.  The range I am checking for duplicates is over 700000 rows (1 column).  It takes forever.

Comment: @Drummo2a that was my initial point - conditional formatting is not the way to go, since you'll have to evaluate the formula for every single cell. Either color your cells a different way (which now that I look at it seems to be your question), or use a formula to count duplicates - which it seems like you've already tried.

Comment: @Drummo2a it would probably be faster if you modified the `ColorFunction` to work with `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`, but then instead of using it as UDF, use it within a `Sub` and write the output to the cell you want.

Comment: please forgive, I am a newbie, how do I do this with a Sub.

Comment: @Drummo2a - see my latest edit. Basically as mentioned, modify your original `ColorFunction` to look at `rCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`, but then _instead of using it as a UDF_, use it within a `Sub` and write the output to a cell.

Comment: I down-vote because there's no warning that `Range.DisplayFormat` only works in Excel 2010+.

Comment: @JohnyL - correct, note that the UDF as proposed doesn't use `Range. DisplayFormat`...

Comment: When I apply this is doesn't update the total when a cell changes colour based on conditional formating.  Am I missing a setting?  I have to go back into the formula cell, edit it (without any changes) hit return and it shows the new expected and correct value.

Comment: @Alan try adding [`Application.Volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile) as the first line within the function...

Comment: Tried that and didn't work.  I actually have it working across a range of 30 days and it looks correct. Then I change one of the cell lookup values on another sheet and go back to where this code is and it shows 29 for example.  When I then click into the formula cell and hit return it shows the expected calculation of 15 for example.  I have it saved in a module, presume this is correct?

Comment: Yes it should be saved in a module. I honestly would shy away from using this UDF based on conditionally formatted cells, and instead replicate the logic of the conditional formatting in a regular formula.